# How to bring HTML +JavaScript into TypeScript (Embed a Shopify Buy Button in a .tsx file)

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, shopify, tsx

Trying to integrate Shopify into my personal site.

The frontend is React(NextJS w/ TypeScript). The embed code for the Shopify buy button is a HTML div tag wrapping JavaScript. How can I successfully bring the code into my .tsx file to serve on my fronted?

**Code:**
Here is the code Shopify supplies to embed the Buy Button on a .html page which is in in HTML and JS:

```
<div id='collection-component-XXXXXXXXXX9'></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
(function () {
  var scriptURL = 'https://sdks.shopifycdn.com/buy-button/latest/buy-button-storefront.min.js';
  if (window.ShopifyBuy) {
    if (window.ShopifyBuy.UI) {
      ShopifyBuyInit();
    } else {
      loadScript();
    }
  } else {
    loadScript();
  }
  function loadScript() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.async = true;
    script.src = scriptURL;
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(script);
    script.onload = ShopifyBuyInit;
  }
  function ShopifyBuyInit() {
    var client = ShopifyBuy.buildClient({
      domain: 'xxxxxxxxxxx.myshopify.com',
      storefrontAccessToken: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    });
    ShopifyBuy.UI.onReady(client).then(function (ui) {
      ui.createComponent('collection', {
        id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        node: document.getElementById('collection-component-XXXXXXXXXXX9'),
        moneyFormat: '%24%7B%7Bamount%7D%7D',
        options: {
  "product": {
    "styles": {
      "product": {
        "@media (min-width: 601px)": {
          "max-width": "calc(25% - 20px)",
          "margin-left": "20px",
          "margin-bottom": "50px",
          "width": "calc(25% - 20px)"
        },
        "img": {
          "height": "calc(100% - 15px)",
          "position": "absolute",
          "left": "0",
          "right": "0",
          "top": "0"
        },
        "imgWrapper": {
          "padding-top": "calc(75% + 15px)",
          "position": "relative",
          "height": "0"
        }
      },
      "title": {
        "font-size": "14px",
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "button": {
        ":hover": {
          "background-color": "#10002b"
        },
        "background-color": "#100030",
        ":focus": {
          "background-color": "#10452b"
        },
        "padding-left": "35px",
        "padding-right": "35px"
      },
      "price": {
        "color": "#086cce"
      },
      "compareAt": {
        "color": "#0000ce"
      },
      "unitPrice": {
        "color": "#0000ce"
      }
    },
    "text": {
      "button": "Add to cart"
    }
  },
  "productSet": {
    "styles": {
      "products": {
        "@media (min-width: 601px)": {
          "margin-left": "-20px"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "modalProduct": {
    "contents": {
      "img": false,
      "imgWithCarousel": true,
      "button": false,
      "buttonWithQuantity": true
    },
    "styles": {
      "product": {
        "@media (min-width: 601px)": {
          "max-width": "100%",
          "margin-left": "0px",
          "margin-bottom": "0px"
        }
      },
      "button": {
        ":hover": {
          "background-color": "#10452b"
        },
        "background-color": "#124d30",
        ":focus": {
          "background-color": "#10452b"
        },
        "padding-left": "35px",
        "padding-right": "35px"
      },
      "title": {
        "font-family": "Helvetica Neue, sans-serif",
        "font-weight": "bold",
        "font-size": "26px",
        "color": "#40004c"
      },
      "price": {
        "font-family": "Helvetica Neue, sans-serif",
        "font-weight": "normal",
        "font-size": "14px",
        "color": "#40004c"
      },
      "compareAt": {
        "font-family": "Helvetica Neue, sans-serif",
        "font-weight": "normal",
        "font-size": "11.9px",
        "color": "#40004c"
      },
      "unitPrice": {
        "font-family": "Helvetica Neue, sans-serif",
        "font-weight": "normal",
        "font-size": "11.9px",
        "color": "#40004c"
      }
    },
    "text": {
      "button": "Add to cart"
    }
  },
  "option": {},
  "cart": {
    "styles": {
      "button": {
        ":hover": {
          "background-color": "#10002b"
        },
        "background-color": "#100000",
        ":focus": {
          "background-color": "#10002b"
        }
      }
    },
    "text": {
      "total": "Subtotal",
      "button": "Checkout"
    },
    "popup": false
  },
  "toggle": {
    "styles": {
      "toggle": {
        "background-color": "#120030",
        ":hover": {
          "background-color": "#10002b"
        },
        ":focus": {
          "background-color": "#10002b"
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
      });
    });
  }
})();
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably put that entire `<script>` in the `index.html` and then just add `<div id='collection-component-XXXXXXXXXX9'></div>` to component where you want your embed to be.

Comment: You are wondering how to convert JS to Typescript? Just work backwards! Since you know what Typescript generates JS.

Comment: @DavidLazar Did you mean to comment on the response? Sounds like it was meant for the post. Because here there is no need to convert the code to TS

Comment: You asked how to bring your JS into TSX. If you just want to paste JS in there, go for it!

Comment: @DavidLazar I tried first to just add the JS in but it gives errors like "Property 'ShopifyBuy' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'" so not possible.

Comment: And that is why I suggested you simply reverse the JS into TS and then those errors go away. You asked! I delivered!